# Take sin of expression with units in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

## The main problem

The problem is that when I take the sin of 30 degrees (with units) I can't use N to find a numeric answer. A minimum example is below.

```
from sympy import sin, N
from sympy.physics.units import deg
N(sin(30*deg))
```

So is there either

- A way to take the sin of something with units?
- Is there a simple quick way to remove the units?

---

## Known partial solution

I am aware of the `.args` way of getting the numbers but my problem with that is that if I do something like

```
from sympy import sin, N
from sympy.physics.units import deg, rad, convert_to
number = convert_to(30*deg, rad)
number.args
```

This will yield a `(1/6, pi, rad)`. But it can also yield a tuple with just two parts. So to separate everything out I need a whole other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using units could you just use numbers?

```
>>> from sympy.geometry.polygon import rad, deg
>>> rad(30) # instead of 30*deg
pi/6
>>> deg(pi)
180
```

Otherwise, to do a mass conversion from units to numbers you could change any `Mul` that has the unit `deg` into `rad(Mul/deg)`:

```
>>> from sympy.physics.units import deg
>>> cos(30*deg)
cos(30*deg)
>>> cos(rad(30))
sqrt(3)/2
>>> pats = lambda x:x.is_Mul and x.has(deg), lambda x: rad(x/deg)
>>> cos(30*deg).replace(*pats)
sqrt(3)/2
```